# Possible? to show data from realtime database firebase by pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use html, javascript and jQuery for create a table for show data from realtime database(20 row) and I want to show data by pagination(5 row per page). I try to use jQuery plugin(dataTable) for do pagination it's work with normal data but not work with data from realtime database. 
So I want to know it's possible to show data from realtime database by pagination.

Comment: It's certainly possible.

Comment: Can you suggest me for do this?. I never see any tutorial or the article like my question.